# На каком языке программирования лучше создавать игры?

Tags: javascript, python, разработка-игр

Что лучше, для создания игр, **Javascript** или **Python**?

(не имею в виду игры по типу gta, pubg и т.п. . А какие-нибудь **платформеры**)

Знаю, что есть c# и c++. Но всё-таки хочется узнать про **js** и **py**.

Comment: Если платформеры - то лучше использовать какую-нибудь среду разработки, заточенную под платформеры, например [corona](https://ru.coronalabs.com/)

Comment: думаю в вашем случае лучше тот который вы знакомы на ты

Comment: @AzizUmarov я вообще не знаком с программированием (разбираюсь пока только в html/css) спрашиваю для того, чтобы знать, какой язык лучше учить для начала

Comment: Для начала изучите тот в котором найдете спеца (coach) что вхождение было быстрым. А затем освоив программирование изучить нужный не проблема

Comment: @AzizUmarov да я вроде уже нашёл пару нужных курсов, остальное - дело времени и труда

Comment: курсы это хорошо а нужен спец который оценит труд и объяснить что и почему

Comment: @AzizUmarov да, я понимаю. Но проблема в том, что в моём окружении нету таких людей, а поступать в школы по программированию (по крайней мере в моём городе), мне уже поздно.
И репетиторов не наблюдается

Comment: Ну с таким настроением вы далеко не уедите

Comment: @AzizUmarov справлюсь, как-нибудь

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @Алексей Всякая штука типа Яндекс практикума — далеко не такая серьезная как кажется. А чаще всего — выкачивенные денег и "развод". Если правда хочется научиться — учитесь сами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И то и то можно использовать вполне успешно, но на мой взгляд [python](/questions/tagged/python) всё-таки лучше. Т.к. во-первых [python](/questions/tagged/python) легче изучить, потому что язык очень простой, и во-вторых в [python](/questions/tagged/python) кроме библиотек типа [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame) (имеет все инструменты для создания простых платформеров и вообще практически любых 2D игр) есть так же игровой движок **Godot**, (программирование игр в нем происходит на специальном языке, синтаксис которого на 95% повторяет python), но как вы понимаете полноценный игровой движок уже позволяет делать любые игры, при том гораздо быстрее чем писать с нуля.

**P.S.** Но всё-таки логичнее было бы изучить например c# и делать игры на unity .

Comment: я только начинаю изучать программирование, пока не хочу учить c#, ибо python легче, поэтому для начала я по-видимому лучше буду учить его

Comment: @Алексей Питон тоже может пригодиться в серьезном геймдеве — на нем можно писать серверную часть.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica ну, тем лучше для меня

Comment: @Алексей ;) удачи в освоении! Кстати подороге освоения питона может захотеться "свернуть" на что-то более питонное: сайты, нейронные сети, Data Science и т.д.